# Find file and rename on one command in bash

Tags: linux, find, filenames, rename, mv

How can I find a file in a RHEL 7 server and rename it? Can this be done in one command?

For example, I could:

```
find . -name filename
```

then `cd` to the directory then `mv filename.conf filename2.conf`, but I want to do this all in one line.

Comment: can u give an example and share the details of where you are struggling...

Comment: I know how to do it in multiple commands. find . -name filename then cd to directory then mv filename.conf filename2.conf. is there a way to do all in one command? Basically getting output of find command do the mv command in one command?

Comment: Edit the question to fill your comment's information in the original question. Then `man find` and read `-execdir`

Comment: how do you know that you'd only find one file? What if the file isn't found? If you have the full (unique) path to a file, you wouldn't need to find it. I don't know what the use-case is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `execdir` flag.

```
  find . -type f -name <original_file_name> -execdir mv {} <new_file_name> \;
```

Comment: Beware that this will not rename the file in its current subdir, but move it to the working directory. You'll need `execdir` instead

Comment: @Philippos I'm sorry about the error. You're right. It's supposed to be execdir. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and to all contributors as well for suggesting other ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename `file.conf` to `file2.conf`, use `find` with the `-exec` option:

```
find . -name "*.conf" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.conf}2.conf"' sh {} \;
```

Each filename `{}` is passed as parameter `$1` to a new shell process started with the `-exec` option where the `mv` command is executed.

- `${1%.conf}` is a shell parameter expansion and removes suffix `.conf` from the filename
- `2.conf` adds the new suffix to the filename

If you want to test your command before executing it, add an `echo` to it like:

```
find . -name "*.conf" -type f -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.conf}2.conf"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: very handy!.  addition,  %% for maximum length suffix.  # for prefix, ## for maxim length prefix, / / for substitution.  see your local man page for details.  location can very.